# validate file before upload

Tags: python, django

I have different categories like `English`,`French` and I've applied `key` `language = models.ForeignKey(Category)` I want to validate the file before it upload to disk. 
I want if category is `english` then file upload to `english/album_name` if category is `french` then file upload to `french/album_name`. I've written `forms.py` file. But no idea. Thanks in advance

Models.py

```
    class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True,max_length=100,help_text="Suggested value automatically generated from name. Must be unique.")

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True,max_length=100,help_text="Suggested value automatically generated from name. Must be unique.")
    path = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    albumid = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artist)
    music = models.ForeignKey(Music)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='media/mp3_files')
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from db.song.models import Song

class SongAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = Song
     # No idea what to do next :-?
    def clean_file(self):
      file = self.cleaned_data["file"]
      if file:
           if file._size > 10*1024*1024:
             raise ValidationError("Audio file too large ( > 10mb )")
           if not file.content-type in ["audio/mpeg","audio/..."]:
                raise ValidationError("Content-Type is not mpeg")
```

Comment: "I want to validate the file before it upload to disk"  How?  The file can only be validated by actually examining the bytes.  How can the bytes be examined without being uploaded to a computer which can examine the bytes?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is to validate it after upload, but before saving it really.

When files are uploaded, they are in a temporary folder, so you can do all checks you want before saving it to the appropriate folder.

However, if you really mean pre-upload checks, you have to use Javascript (because it is client-side). But, don't forget that you should "never trust user input", and that includes what Javascript does, because user can change the Javascript code.

Comment: Ok thanks and what about  `I want if category is english then file upload to english/album_name if category is french then file upload to french/album_name. I've written forms.py file.`

Comment: I think the two first code blocks here are what you need: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/